# Would this be a problem that Survival Analysis can tackle? The problem deals with localized durations and uncensored data

Tags: r, survival, exponential-distribution

I am trying to fit a model in R that doesn't have censoring. In other words, I know that each event will eventually happen. There are several experimental groups with people in each group receiving surgery. However, each group receives the surgery on different dates. I only have data for who died. Hence, my data set so happens to look like:

```
> data.frame
Group     Person   D = Day of Death since GROUP received surgery     Age
1         7        5                                                   45
1         8        12                                                  62
1         9        85                                                  55
1         10       102                                                 34
2         11       3                                                   44
2         12       7                                                   72
2         13       25                                                  81
2         14       56                                                  63
2         15       78                                                  57
3         16       2                                                   66
3         17       15                                                  28
3         18       88                                                  77
3         19       150                                                 54
```

The above is different than usual survival analysis data in that the days till death are dependent on the group a person belongs to. Meaning, each person within a group received the surgery on the same day, with each group's surgery date possibly different than another group's surgery date.

Also, what is different here is that I only have data for people who died. Hence, there isn't any censoring (I believe).

The Age variable is a covariates.

If I were to try to model the hazard function as exponential, would it make sense to do this in R?

Meaning, if I thought the hazard function looked like:

$h_i(t) = \beta_0 + \beta_1Age_i + \beta_2log(Age_i)$

where the log is to account for any potential logarithmic effects.

And if my survial function were:

$S(t) = e^{-h_i(t)*t}$,

would the following R model do just that?

`survreg(Surv(D) ~ Age+log(Age), data = data.frame,  dist ="exponential")`

Would I have any troubles? I ask this because this isn't really your standard survival analysis problem. Thank you!

Comment: censoring occurs even when you know for certain the event will eventually happen. What matters is whether all your observations have the event time recorded (e.g. if some are still alive when your study ends, or are lost to the study by other means)